# What happened when I typed cd //

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I accidentally typed `cd //` instead of `cd ..` and something weird happened.
The directory `//` doesn't exist, what's going on here exactly.

```
root@root:/var/www/html# cd //
root@root://# pwd
//
root@root://# cd ..
root@root://#
```

Comment: // is usually the same as / . cd // is same as cd /